# Using StatusBar plugin works on simulator, not device

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, ios7-statusbar

I'm at my wits end at this point, trying to get past the IOS7 issue whereby the statusbar overlaps the top of my app.  The steps I've taken are:

- `phonegap plugins add org.apache.cordova.statusbar`
- Adding the following to my main config.xml:

  `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>`
- From reading various SO posts, I've tried several times adding/removing both the plugin and the ios platform.

The plugin now successfully adjusts the status bar behavior on the simulator (running `cordova run ios`) but when I use Phonegap Build to actually run it on the device, alas the status bar still overlays my app webview.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: as you only have the problem when you use phonegap build, the problem should be on the config.xml. Anyway, try running locally on the device with cordova run ios --device

Comment: Yeah, on the simulator it works as expected (as I mentioned).  It's only on the device that I'm continuing to have problems.  Which is, needless to say, frustrating.

Comment: If you use cordova run ios --device it should install and run on the device

Answer (score 0):

You can open up `MainViewController.c` (I think that's what it's called in Cordova), find the `viewDidLoad:` method and insert code like this:

```
if (IS_IOS7_OR_LATER) {
    CGRect *frame = self.webview.frame;
    frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    self.webview.frame = frame;
}
```

where IS_IOS7_OR_LATER is a macro or some other code to check if we're running on iOS 7 or later.

Comment: he has the problem with phonegap build, he can't edit any native code there

Comment: Yes he can, Cordova does not overwrite the changes.

Comment: He is using phonegap build, that is an online service that compiles the html, css and javascript into an app, he can't change native code there

Comment: Thanks for the attempt though :)